# How can I remove a file from a commit of a private branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit

I was working on master branch modifiying 10 files and adding 5 new ones.
I realized that one of the files should not be modified and I should unstage it as the original version was correct.
I also decided to continue my work in a branch.
I did a: `git checkout -b newBranch`
Then I did a `git add` and `git commit` of all my work to the branch.
But I forgot that I had to unstage one of the files!
So now the only solution I can think of is to copy the original file from the master branch to my branch and then adding and commiting to replace the modified file.
I think this should work, but I think it will be strange to merge later my last commit of my private branch with my master branch and deliver a file same as the one on the master.
Is there a better way to deal with this mess?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you didn't share this branch, you have several solutions.

---

**commit --amend**

If you just committed all your files, you could do

```
#Restore the file
git checkout HEAD -- my/file.txt

#Fix your commit
git add my/file.txt
git commit --amend
```

It will redo your last commit with your file fixed

**rebase -i**

There's another way a bit more complicated, but a bit more flexible. Even if you don't use it today, it might save you some other time.

You could squash your commits.

Let's say you have

- one commit where you added all your files (let's call it `abc`)
- one commit where you retrieve the older version of the file you didn't want to change (let's call it `def`)

You could just do `git rebase -i HEAD^^`. It will open a text editor with your two last commits, like

```
pick abc first commit message
pick def second commit message
```

replace it to

```
pick abc first commit message
fixup def second commit message
```

then save and exit, and git will merge those two commits

---

**Edit1**: some explanations on the 2nd solution to follow-up on the comment

`git rebase -i HEAD^^` means "let me change my tree of commit, starting from `HEAD^^`" (And `HEAD^^` means "[the parent of the parent of my current commit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References)")

It will then open a text editor with a list of all the commits involved, and it will let you choose an action for each of those commits. The list of the possible actions is presented at the bottom of file.

`pick`, the default action, means "don't change this commit. `squash` means "merge this commit and the previous one". `fixup` is "merge this commit and the previous one, and re-use the commit message"

Anyway, if you're not sure of what you're doing, you can tag the initial commit before doing this kind of manipulation. Example:

```
git tag safetyNet
git rebase -i HEAD^^
#damned, I screwed up
git checkout safetyNet
```

---

**Edit2** to answer other comment

If you already pushed your branch to a remote, and if you're the only one to use it, then it's not a big deal. However, you'll have to "force" the push. Here is why

Let's say you have the following commits:

```
A -- B
     L  newBranch | commit with the file you didn't want to modify
```

Since you pushed, that's what you have both on your local and your remote repos.

After fixing it (using either solution 1 or 2), you'll have in your local repo

```
A -- B2
 \   L newBranch |fixed commit
  \
   \- B
      L commit with the file you didn't want to modify, not on any branch anymore
```

If you try `git push origin newBranch` it will fail since you can't [fast forward](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-2.html) from `B` to `B2`.

So you'll need to do `git push -f origin newBranch` to tell git "I know what I'm doing; go ahead and push anyway".

Reading http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches might  help to clarify those notions

Comment: `git rebase HEAD^^` this rebases in my private branch? What does this do? Also I am not sure what is `pick/fixup`

Comment: "As long as you didn't share this branch" I have pushed it to remote if this is what you mean.But I am the only one working on it.

Comment: Since you're the only one to work with it, you're safe. However, note that you'll have to `git push -f` afterwards

Comment: `git push -f`?For which approach of the 2?Why do I need that?I am sorry but I am not very experienced with git and I am still struggling with it